# Get javascript variables in php cordova

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

Hi I try to get the geolocation of the user using cordova. The longitude and latitude should be get in php and cookies should be created with these values. But when I start the application on my device a blank white screen become show. How can I get the javascript variables with php right?

```
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
latitude = position.coords.latitude;
longitude = position.coords.longitude;          
window.location.href = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/loc/www/login.php?latitude=" + latitude;
window.location.href = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/loc/www/login.php?longitude=" + longitude;
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

<?php

$latitude = $_GET["latitude"];
$longitude = $_GET["longitude"];
$t = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
setcookie("latitude", $latitude, $t);
setcookie("longitude", $longitude, $t);

?>
```

Comment: You have to make a post to the server. From your code, you are trying to access the $_GET["latitude"], but they are set by javascript AFTER the page has loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have PHP variable combined with javascript, please fix to this:

```
window.location.href = "http://<?php  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/loc/www/login.php?latitude=" + latitude;
```

You change the location previously and then you try to change again, this will not work:

```
window.location.href = "http://<?php  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/loc/www/login.php?longitude=" + longitude;
```

Why you don't try to create a API to be consumed by your cordova App,  send the location to the webservice when cordova is ready?, you could send both values, latitude and longitude to the server and locally keep those values.

Comment: now I get an error while getting the 2 variables. Notice: Undefined index: longitude...

Comment: The error is correct, you are trying to combine the server side, that render the page first and the client side that execute after the server side, will always redirect when it get the latitude value and never get the logitude value. That's why I am suggesting you to create a web service, please check the cordova documentation approach.